# переход по ссылке при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть ссылка и при наведении она должна переходить по ссылке, но не открывать новую вкладку. Заранее благодарю за ответы

Comment: Наведении? Не клике?

Comment: наведении. window.open вроде. Но меня на новую вкладку перекидвает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {    
    e.target.click();    
});
```

```html
<a href="google.ru" id="test">GO</a>
```

У ссылки, замечу, нет атрибута `target="_blank"`